# Regression and calibration/inverse regression - the same?

Tags: r, regression, terminology, inverse-prediction

In principle, I've a simple task:

There are some physical quantities (*temperature*, *pressure* and *molecule number*) measured by a sensor and I want to use them to regress the concenctration of a gas. I will do this by using a multiple regression.

**First question**: Is a *simple* multiple regression sufficient or is there something "advanced" more suitable?

**Second question**: When I've done this, the fit will be used later to get the concentration for certain input parameters (*temperature*, *pressure* and *molecule number*). 
I wonder if this isn't a calibration, basically. Or rather, if this is just the same in this case?
I'm not a statistician but, at least, I know that I can choose a [calibrate function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/5.1-3.1/topics/calibrate) or even something else from the [calibrate package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/calibrate/index.html).
Despite from that, I wonder if a calibration is the same as an [inverse regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliced_inverse_regression)?

Comment: Calibration is regression. The only important issue is that simple regression assumes that there is no error in x values. For a calibration we can only assume that there is no error in the "quantities" (whatever we actually want to determine) we have in our calibration standards. Thus, if you want to later measure from samples, you need to do inverse *prediction*, because the raw data from the machine is the y value and what you want to know the x value in your calibration curve. Now, if your sensor measures several quantities and you want to determine the concentration, it becomes difficult,

Comment: because usually this means you need to ensure there is a unique solution by restricting the "calibration space", i.e., the combined ranges of your measured quantities. I think this might be a big issue for you because of the ideal gas law.

Comment: @Roland Thanks a lot! You answered my question so you could write it as an answer? To follow up, I've another question: The background is, the sensor will be mesaured by going through different independent parameters like concentrations, temperatures and moistures and so on. They will result in an independent parameter, the resistance. Later, when the sensor will operate, the resistance will be the independent parameter and the concentration the only (dependent) parameter.
So, first it would be a regression and then an inverse regression, basically.

Comment: When performing an inverse regression, it will be the same model as before, just ignoring all other parameters except of resistance and concentration.
Though I already said it but to proceed, I would perform a multivariate regression and then the above mentioned calibration. 
Is there a specific model or function I should be aware of? Can you tell me? Despite from that, shall I be aware of anything in general (for example errors, what about EoV?)?

Comment: The regression would be `resistence ~ f(concentration)` and you would then predict with the inverse of the function $f^{-1}(resistence)$. The function needs to come from domain knowledge. Maybe it could even be a linear function (for small ranges).

Comment: the function will be fitted through observed parameters in the lab(?).
Shouldn't I be worried about errors somewhere? :)

Comment: I'm assuming you have standards with known concentration? Then the model usually is $y_i = f(x_i) + \varepsilon_i$ and there is your error.

Comment: What means standards? Especially the concentrations will be filled up by hand. And the other devices Idk as I'm not performing the measurements. What is the difference between this "regular" error above and an EoV?
Each of the independent variables will probably have an error?

Comment: On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models it is written: 
"In statistics, errors-in-variables models or measurement error models[1][2][3] are regression models that account for measurement errors in the independent variables. In contrast, standard regression models assume that those regressors have been measured exactly, or observed without error; as such, those models account only for errors in the dependent variables, or responses"
For me, this sounds like applicable to each scenario.

Comment: Standards in your case are samples with known concentration. "known" means measured by a more precise method than the one to be calibrated. (For our gas chromatographs we buy such standards from a commercial supplier. They certify the concentration to an uncertainty that is negligible compared to the measurement uncertainty of  our instruments. You can not mix gas standards with sufficient precision for calibration in most research labs. So, if you don't have a very precise gas analyzer, I'd say you should buy your standards.)

Comment: that's good to know because I know that my colleagues are doing that by hand (I'm just fresh in the company ;p)

Comment: btw, do you know (maybe even certain numbers) how to perform a corresponding measurement of a new sensor? For example, how many sensors, how many data points,..? I guess there are tools or at least rules of thumb how to proceed?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe there is an ISO standard covering this?

Comment: Really, I never knew. And I fear none of my academic or even now private sector knews..  weird. But good to know, thank you! Is it  ISO/TC 69/SC 6 ?

Comment: Possibly also ISO 14956?